# Chinese this and that

Tags: usage

In English, we use *this* to indicate something close to us, or the first one and *that* to indicate something further off, or the next one. Apparently, early English did not have this distinction.

This quote is from [here:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/that#etymonline_v_10712)

> that: From c. 1200 opposed to this as indicating something farther
>   off.

Chinese has 这， 那 which seem to correspond with this, that.

Has Chinese always made a distinction between this and that? In old Chinese was this distinction present?

Comment: Reechen, du sollst mal Antworten schreiben, das weißt du ja. Warum so schüchtern? Hör einmal auf den Leuten hier. Tut ja nicht weh.

Answer (score 7):

The distinction was present early on. In Classical Chinese, *this* is「此」, still used in Modern Chinese, while *that* is「彼」, which is not really used anymore except fossilised in some words.

> 《[詩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Poetry)・唐風・綢繆》：「今夕何夕，見**此**良人！」
>
> 《[易](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching)・小過》：「公弋取**彼**在穴。」

Comment: Also 是, for a more general _this_: 《論》：是可忍，孰不可忍？

Answer (score -1):

"这" also can indicate something has just mentioned.

Comment: Yes, like: I know 1 + 1 is two. I know that. Then 'that' refers to '1 + 1 = 2' Then 'that' is an anaphor, from Greek 'anapherein' literally meaning 'carry back'. I just wondered if the difference between this and that was present in old Chinese. In fact, I'm sure Old English had this distinction too.